# How do I use HttpGet attribute with multiple input parameters ? (and work with swagger)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, http-get, swashbuckle

It works fine with the code below is I only have one parameter but how do I do TWO input parameters? If I just use [HttpGet] then none of the parameters are send though it works fine outside of Swagger. Help ?

```
//[HttpGet]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[HttpGet("{caseId}")]
public ActionResult Get(string caseId, string fileName)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: is this asp.net core?

Comment: why you don't use a ViewModel instead of those 2 parameters?

Comment: yes this is asp.net core

Comment: The resource can be identified using caseId and fileName together? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood well your question. You want your `get` method to receive both parameteres, and show it in `Swashbuckle`?

Comment: yes. All the examples I seen use one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the FromUri or querystring attributes in your method signature

```
[Consumes("application/json")]
[HttpGet("{caseId}")]
public ActionResult Get(string caseId, [FromUri] string fileName)
{
    return null;
}
```

or

```
[Consumes("application/json")]
[HttpGet("{caseId}")]
public ActionResult Get(string caseId, [QueryString] string fileName)
{
    return null;
}
```

This should now document in swagger showing that the caseId is part of the route and that the fileName should be specified.

Comment: Is the best practice to use a ViewModel for anything more than one input parameter

Answer (score 1):

I was just experimenting with this.

I found the following code works with Swagger:

```
[HttpGet("{entityId}/{monthsOfHistory}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DateTime>> GetAsync([FromRoute] int entityId, [FromRoute] int monthsOfHistory)
```